# Ionic angular Update $scope variable after click a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I want to update my $scope variable in the moment that i click a save button, basically I'm trying to update a profile name, so i need when i push the save button this new name be displayed instantly in the navbar beside a image profile, i tried the follow way... but does not work for me, i did use $apply:

controller.js

```js
.controller('ProfileCtrl', function($ionicPlatform, $cordovaMedia, $scope, Words, Utilities, $timeout) {
   
   $scope.save = function(){

var content = toTitleCase($scope.editWordRow.title);
       //$scope.profilename = '';
        
       $timeout(function () {
         $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.profilename = content;
            console.log('profile name tiene esto, deberia mostrarse al salir de guardar: ' + $scope.profilename);
         });
       }, 2000);
};

// the follow $scope function is called when the controller starts

$scope.getProfileRow = function() {
    Words.getProfileSimple().then(function(single){
      if (single === null || single === undefined) {
      $scope.editWordRow = {
          title: null,
          congrats_path: null,
          name_sound_path: null,
          profile_image_path: null
      };  
      
     
      }
      else 
      {
      $scope.editWordRow = single;
      $scope.profilename = single.title;

      }
    
          
    });
      
  };
});
```

menu.html

```js
 <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle="left"></button>
        
        <div style="margin: 0 auto; width:30px" ><img src="img/iconos/logo.png" width="30px" height="30px"></div>
        <div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
            <h4 style="color:#fff !important; margin: 5px !important;" >{{profilename}}</h4>
        </div>
 </ion-nav-buttons>
```

The view where the save() function is called is:

inicio2.html

```js
 <ion-nav-buttons side="right">
        
        
        <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-ios-checkmark-outline" ng-click="save()">&nbsp;</button>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
```

There is a problem if i call save() function in another view?

thanks, regards i will appreciate any help!

Comment: Yes, you have to call save() function inside your controller.

Comment: I'm calling save() function in my controller, you meant, i need to call the save() in the same view?, the problem is i need to show the profile name in the navbar that's why I use {{profilename} in the menu.html, there is another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update a value in a view that is not controlled by the current controller, you have 2 ways of doing so:

1. Fire an event and catch it on the proper controller that actually control the menu.
2. Use a service that is a dependency for both controller, and store the value of the variable in that service.

### Edit:

Where the variable "profileName" is attached to the scope for 2 way data binding and then changed on user input, you can do:

```
$scope.$watch('profileName', function(changedProfileName) {
  $scope.$emit('profileName:changed', changedProfileName);
});
```

And then, in your navbar controller, you can catch the event:

```
$rootScope.$on('profileName:changed', function(e, newProfileName) {
  $scope.profileNameToShow = newProfileName;
});
```

Comment: I'm a little confused with your suggestions, can you please explain me how to do one of those?

Answer (score 0):

For a typical app the navbar, footer are shared across all the views and if you need to share the scope values in header, footer and make them same across the app you can assign them using the `$rootScope.profilename`. This way whenever you update `$rootScope.profilename`, it will be reflected across the app.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, the changes will be reflected instantly??, i tried without different results...

Comment: I'm trying to use the scope variable in menu.html view, because i want to see my profile name always in the navbar, i tried the rootScope but still does not working, so i do not know what is the problem here. Basically the $scope.profilename is changed when i push the save() function (button), this function is in the ProfileCtrl controller, so in my menu.html view i call this controller `<div ng-controller="ProfileCtrl">
            <h4 style="color:#fff !important; margin: 5px !important;" >{{profilename}}</h4>
        </div>` but nothing happens, this is driving me crazy